# What does the phrase "has been" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

> Although he used to be a box office attraction, he's a **has been** now.

Does the **has been** mean "over" or something else in the sentence above?

Ex :

> I went to the party at 9pm, but the party was has been by 8pm?

Please correct me.

Comment: As a noun "has been" means somebody whose relevance is over.  (You can tell the usage is as a noun, since it's preceded by an article, in this case, *a*.)  Your sentence means the actor used to be popular, but his acting career is over

Comment: It's nearly always hyphenated. From [*The Home Stretch*](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Loudon_Wainwright_III:The_Home_Stretch) by Loudon Wainwright III: *At least you've been a **has-been** \ And not just a **never-was***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression has nothing to do with your example.

A [has been](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/has-been?q=has%20been) is

> A person or thing considered to be outmoded or no longer of any
>   significance

For example, politicians who are voted out of office (usually) tend to lose influence very quickly. Some go on to be elder statesmen or women, but it depends on how their time in office ended.

Also, the entertainment industry is littered with has beens; people who were once box office draws or sold huge numbers of albums, but most people hardly even remember them now.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]